# как хранить данные локально на устройстве (swift3+iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Пишу приложение, которое должно собирать данные каждый день (к примеру пользователь каждый день вводит число) и создавать график исходя из значений.

Кто расскажет, или кинет валидную ссылку, как хранить весь этот массив(хоть и не большой) локально на устройстве всегда, предположим весь год?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults

Answer (score 0):

```
 // save value 
 let dict:[String:String] = ["date":"number"]
 UserDefaults.standard.set(dict, forKey: "dict")
// get value
 let result = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "dict")
```

Comment: и есть ли ограничения на хранение данных, например не больше 1Гб или сколько нибудь записей?

Comment: Это просто plist файл, в котором будут сохраняться пара ключ-значение. Насчет ограничений не могу сказать, поищите информацию в гуугле.

Answer (score 0):

UserDefaults не очень хороший способ хранения данных

Смотри в сторону баз данных

https://habrahabr.ru/post/303512/